# Having 2 graphs on the same chart when they have different data sizes. Any ideas?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have:

```
List<string> dates1 = new List<string>();
List<string> values1 = new List<string>();

List<string> dates2 = new List<string>();
List<string> values2 = new List<string>();
```

That will accept my data ranges from a datasource.  Dates1 and Values1 have 128 values in each list.

The dates1 data looks like this {"5/29/2015 11:02",....,"5/30/2015 11:02",....,"5/31/2015 11:02",....,"6/1/2015 11:02",....,"6/2/2015 11:02",....,"6/3/2015 11:02"} with the in between data points being different times within that day for a total 128 values.

The dates2 data looks like this {"5/29/2015 9:05","5/30/2015 9:05","5/31/2015 9:05","6/1/2015 9:05","6/2/2015 9:05","6/3/2015 9:05"} with 7 total values.

The two graphs separately look correct and like this:
[image: Both Graphs]

The problem is getting both graphs on the same chart correctly.

If I create 2 series on the chart I will get this:
[image: firstTry]

I have seen some advice to use Chart1.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel(); and this is what I get:
[image: secondTry]

The two graph should be spread out evenly over each other but the x-axis for the 2nd series is being disrupted for some reason.  Is this even possible to do?  I would greatly appreciate any help you can spare.

Here is the c# code if interested:

```
List<string> dates = new List<string>();
List<string> values = new List<string>();

List<string> dates2 = new List<string>();
List<string> values2 = new List<string>();

//*****SQL connection and code that populates the Lists is here*****

Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(dates, values);

Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StepLine;
Chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;
Chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 1;
Chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = "#VALY, #VALX";

//BIND THE DATA TO THE CHART
Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
Chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(dates2, values2);


Chart1.Series[1].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StepLine;
Chart1.Series[1].Color = Color.Green;
Chart1.Series[1].BorderWidth = 2;
Chart1.Series[1].ToolTip = "#VALY, #VALX";

//SET THE IMAGE OUTPUT TYPE TO BE JPEG
Chart1.ImageType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageType.Jpeg;

//ADD A PLACE HOLDER CHART AREA TO THE CHART
Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
Chart1.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel();  // THIS IS THE COMBINING OF AXES
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 200, 200, 200);
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 200, 200, 200);

//ADD A PLACE HOLDER LEGEND TO THE CHART
//SHOW THE LEGEND
Chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend());
Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
```

Edit: having dates, in the 2nd dataset, that match up perfectly to dates in the first seems to fix it.  The issue is the dates will never match because they are taken at different times and has a time precision.  Surely, there is a way to do this that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out.  One issue I had was pulling in my date as a string instead of DateTime.  I switched to DateTime and it fixed the issue while using a data table and binding with Chart1.DataBindCrossTable.

```
var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Series", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

//looping through SQL datasource for first series
    while(){
        dt.Rows.Add("Today", date, value);
    }
//looping through SQL datasource for second series
while(){
    dt.Rows.Add("Yesterday", date, value);
}

Chart1.Series.Clear();
Chart1.DataBindCrossTable(dt.Rows, "Series", "Date", "Value", "");
```

[image: answer]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement using Syncfusion chart by setting columnIndex property for each axis. columnIndex is used to split the chart horizontally so that we can place series without overlapping.
Following Screenshots illustrate this
 [image]

We have prepared a sample based on your requirements. Please find the sample from below link.

Sample Link:
    http://jsfiddle.net/jr8x19vz/55/

Syncfusion also offers ASP.NET wrappers powered by Essential Studio for Javascript, providing client-side rendering of HTML 5-Javascript controls. You can get more information about Syncfusion’s ASP.Net suite from the following location,

```
http://www.syncfusion.com/products/aspnet
```

You can view the demos from the following link,
    http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web

Also take a look at our community license which provides free access to our entire products,

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Please let me know, if you have any changes.

Thanks,

Jayavigneshwaran